# I use vue-router and jQuery in the template,when i switch router $(document).ready() is failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I do not know jQuery in vue correct usage. When I refresh page, `$(document).ready()` has a role. But when I switch the page through vue-router, `$(document).ready()` does not work.

```vue
<template>
    <div id="photo_wrap">
        <div class="photo_frame" v-for="(photo,index) in photos">
            <img v-bind:src=" 'src/assets/photo/' + index + '.jpg' ">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import $ from 'jquery'
    export default {
        name: 'photo',
        data() {
            return {
                photos: [
                    {},{},{},{},{}
                ]
            }
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        console.log('something')
    })

</script>
```

Comment: right-click, view source of new route. is jQuery included? not? make sure it's included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of relying on `$(document).ready()` in a vue webapp, you can use one of the [lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) for this purpose. You can try using [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) as it comes pretty close to  `$(document).ready()`:

> Called after the instance has just been mounted where el is replaced by the newly created vm.$el. If the root instance is mounted to an in-document element, vm.$el will also be in-document when mounted is called.

You can hook it like this:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'photo',
        data() {
            return {
                photos: [
                    {},{},{},{},{}
                ]
            }
        },
        mounted () {
          console.log('something')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you've probably got the answer you were looking for, but for those who came here to find a way to use jQuery inside vue:

you should just add a script tag on your **index.html** file and after that you can use **$** variable whenever the component is created by vue. just like one of life cycle hooks that [Saurabh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479515/5284370) mentioned, or as a method invoked by a v-on directive.

e.g.:

```
<template>
    ///get user name and password here through inputs///
    <button v-on:click="submit"> submit me please</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'something',
    data() {
        return {
            username : '',
            password : '',
            baseUrl : 'felan.com'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {

            $.post(this.baseUrl + '/member/login', {
                username: this.username,
                password: this.password,
            }).then((response) => {
                if (response.valid) {
                    //do something
                } else {
                    //do something else
                }
            }).fail(() => console.log('failed'))
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```