# jquery geocomplete not working with vue js

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, vue.js, geocode

When I wrap a form with jquery geocomplete in a Vue modal, the geocomplete stops working.  I'm not sure how to fix it so that geocomplete works when the modal is active.

Here is a working example without Vue or a modal:
https://jsfiddle.net/3gzovugy/68/

Here is the same example, wrapped in the vue site's example modal, that won't geocode.  Any suggestions?
https://jsfiddle.net/3gzovugy/96/

```
<div id="app">
  <button id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">Show Modal</button>
  <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
    <div slot="body">
      <form>
        <div class="item">
          <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Look up your address" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <input class="cat_textbox" id="houseNo" data-geo="street_number" type="text" placeholder="House Number" maxlength="50" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <input class="cat_textbox" id="street" data-geo="route" type="text" placeholder="street" maxlength="50" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <input class="cat_textbox red" id="BillingAddress" data-geo="street_address" type="text" placeholder="Billing Address" maxlength="50" name="BillingAddress" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </modal>
</div>


  <template id="modal-template">
    <transition name="modal">
      <div class="modal-mask">
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
          <div class="modal-container">

            <div class="modal-header">
              <slot name="header">
                default header
              </slot>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
              <slot name="body">
                default body
              </slot>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
              <slot name="footer">
                default footer
                <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                  OK
                </button>
              </slot>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your `geocomplete` related code is in `$(document).ready(function()`. Taking inspiration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479515/1610034), you can move code inside  `document.ready` to  one of the [lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) for this purpose. You can try using [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) as it comes pretty close to $(document).ready():

```
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template',
  mounted () {
    $("#autocomplete").geocomplete({
    details: "form div",
    detailsAttribute: "data-geo",
    types: ["(cities)"],
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: "in"
    }
  });
  }
})
```

With these changes, you code starts to show suggestion: check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3gzovugy/98/). You may need some other UI changes to see the `geocomplete`  dropdown on top.