# Compile simple html via Vue.compile method

Tags: vue.js

I've got a problem with the Vue.compile method.
I use jquery.datatables with Vue2 and want to use 'child row' functionality, for details please look into following link:
https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

I want to use datatable the same way as described in the link above, but I don't know how can I implement through Vue.component method.

Could you please help me out with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Please see my vue file.

```js
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- BEGIN EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->
            <div class="portlet light ">
                <div class="portlet-body">
                    <div class="table-toolbar">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button id="sample_editable_1_new" class="btn sbold green"> Add New
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--<div class="col-md-6">-->
                                <!--<div class="btn-group pull-right">-->
                                    <!--<button class="btn green  btn-outline dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tools-->
                                        <!--<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>-->
                                    <!--</button>-->
                                    <!--<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">-->
                                        <!--<li>-->
                                            <!--<a href="javascript:;">-->
                                                <!--<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print </a>-->
                                        <!--</li>-->
                                        <!--<li>-->
                                            <!--<a href="javascript:;">-->
                                                <!--<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Save as PDF </a>-->
                                        <!--</li>-->
                                        <!--<li>-->
                                            <!--<a href="javascript:;">-->
                                                <!--<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Export to Excel </a>-->
                                        <!--</li>-->
                                    <!--</ul>-->
                                <!--</div>-->
                            <!--</div>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-checkable order-column" id="datatable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID </th>
                                <th>Name </th>
                                <th>Room type </th>
                                <th>Actions </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="odd gradeX"
                                v-for='item in data'
                                :class="(index+1 % 2 == 0) ? 'odd' : 'even'">
                                <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                                <td>{{item.roomType}}</td>
                                <!--<td><input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="20" :value='item.available'></td>-->
                                <td class="no-sortable">
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button  @click='current = item' type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-edit_action">
                                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                                            <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Remove</button>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script type='text/babel'>
    import fileUpload from '../../directives/fileUpload.vue';
    export default{
        data(){
            return {
                data: [],
                dataIds: [],
                bedTypes: [],
                current: null
            }
        },
        props: {
            schema: { type: Object }
        },
        beforeMount() {
            this.data = [{
                id:20,
                name: 'Marriott',
                roomType: 'Luxe',
                available: 10
            }]
        },
        mounted() {
            this.addBedType();
            this.data.map((item) => this.dataIds.push(item.id));
            console.log(this);

            function nestedRow(d) {
                return `
                    <td colspan=7>
                        <div class="edit-row_body clearfix">
                            <form novalidate class="form-horizontal" @click="$event.preventDefault()">
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <div class="tour-img-block text-left">
                                        <div class="clearfix text-left hotel-pictures">
                                            <input v-file-upload type="file" name="files[]" format="image" multiple class="file-loading">
                                        </div>
                                        <!--<div class="row">-->
                                        <!--<a href="" class="close-preview">&times;</a>-->
                                        <!--<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=18&txt=Upload new image&w=230&h=240" alt="" class="img-responsive">-->
                                        <!--<button class="btn green sbold btn-block mt">Add New</button>-->
                                        <!--</div>-->
                                        <!--<div class="col-sm-4">-->
                                        <!--<div class="clearfix">-->
                                        <!--<div class='portret-sm'>-->
                                        <!--<a href="" class="close-preview">&times;</a>-->
                                        <!--<img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" class='img-responsive' alt="" >-->
                                        <!--</div>-->
                                        <!--<div class='portret-sm'>-->
                                        <!--<a href="" class="close-preview">&times;</a>-->
                                        <!--<img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" class='img-responsive' alt="" >-->
                                        <!--</div>-->
                                        <!--</div>-->

                                        <!--</div>-->
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="form-group" >
                                            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" style='padding-top: 0;'>Bed Type:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                                <div class='form-group' v-for='type in bedTypes'>
                                                    <div class='col-sm-9 pr-0'>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Bed type" v-model='type.name' />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                    <span v-if="bedTypes.length > 1">
                                                        <button @click='bedTypes.splice(index,1);'  class="close-preview tbl-action">×</button>
                                                    </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <button class="btn green sbold btn-right" type="button" @click="addBedType()" >Add new</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <textarea name="description" id="" cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Room description" class="form-control">
                                        </textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="room size">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Standart Guest">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Additional guest">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="guest amount">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="price (AMD)">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="guest amount">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="price (AMD)">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="guest amount">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="price (AMD)">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="" class="col-xs-2 text-right pr-0">Meal Options</label>
                                        <div class="col-xs-8 meal-opts" >
                                            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                                <label class="btn green">
                                                    <input type="radio" class="toggle"> Included </label>
                                                <label class="btn green">
                                                    <input type="radio" class="toggle"> Breakfast </label>
                                                <label class="btn green active">
                                                    <input type="radio" class="toggle"> 3meals/day </label>
                                                <label class="btn green">
                                                    <input type="radio" class="toggle"> Carte Blanche </label>
                                                <label class="btn green">
                                                    <input type="radio" class="toggle"> Not Included </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class='edit-row_foot'>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <button class="btn btn-default">Preview</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-success" @click='save()'>Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                    `;
            }

            $(()=> {
                let $dt = $('#datatable').DataTable();

                // Add event listener for opening and closing details
                $dt.on('click', '.btn-edit_action', function () {
                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var row = $dt.row( tr );
                    console.log(row);
                    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                        // This row is already open - close it
                        row.child.hide();
                        tr.removeClass('shown');
                    }
                    else {
                        // Open this row
                        //let compiled = Vue.compile(nestedRow());
                        row.child( nestedRow() ).show();
                        tr.addClass('shown');
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        methods: {
            save() {
                this.current = null;
            },
            remove(id) {
                this.confirmBox("You will not be able to recover this room!", "warning", (confirm) => {
                    if (confirm && id) {
                        const url = this.buildUrl(this.schema.action, [id]);
                        App.blockUI();
                        this.$http
                                .post(url, {_method: 'delete'})
                                .then(() => {
                                    let ind = this.dataIds.indexOf(id);
                                    if (ind > -1) {
                                        this.data.splice(ind,1);
                                        this.dataIds.splice(ind,1);
                                    }
                                    App.alert({message: 'Successfully Deleted!'});
                                })
                                .finally(() => App.unblockUI());

                    }
                });
            },
            addBedType() {
                this.bedTypes.push({
                    name: ''
                });
            }
        },
        directives: { fileUpload }
    }
</script>
<style>
  .meal-opt .btn-group {
    margin-left:10px;
    max-width: 420px;
  }
  .meal-opt .btn.green {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? You can see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41479515/1610034), code written in `$(document).ready` can be moved to vue [mounted](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) hook.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but I'll need to add html in component template, after click a button.
I added snipet